# Sound working incorrectly on HTML webpage

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I noticed a problem with the sounds of my clickable links, in that the sound doesn't always play.

I have the following bit of code at the top of my  section which contains the src to the sound i'm wanting played

```
<audio id="sound1" src="sounds/mouseClick.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

This is where i reference the function to play the sound

```
 <a href="questionnaire1.html" onclick="play()";> <img src="images/nextnewImage.jpg" alt="Take the Questionnaire" style="width:50%; height:auto"></a>
```

And this is the bit of jQuery i've tried implementing to play the sound, which is outwith my body tag, before the closing html tag.

```
      <script>

         play(){

    $('.sound').live('click', function () {
    var sound = $("#sound1")[0];

    sound.load();
    sound.play();

    return false;
});
});
         }


    </script>
```

Comment: `live()` was deprecated back in `jQuery 1.7`. If using version above 1.7 use `on()` function instead.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. My code is unfortunately still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new `Audio` object and pass in the url to the sound file as a parameter.

```js
var audio = new Audio("sounds/mouseClick.wav");

$('#start').on("click", function() {
  audio.play();
});

$('#pause').on("click", function() {
  audio.pause();
});
```

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- add a button and handle this in jQuery !-->
  <div>
    <button id="start">play</button>
    <button id="pause">pause</button>
  </div>
</div>
```